# wpf: resizing a control according to its content

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, grid, resize

I have a control that inherits from Grid, it is a grid of hexagons that are generated dynamically according to the properties.
each of the hexagons is a button and a child of the Grid, and they have a style that displays them as hexagons.

what I want is for the grid to change its size according to the total size of the hexagons.
(I can calculate the exact size needed, but I don't know how to set it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you've got several options. A simple one is calculating the size yourself and assigning to the Grid's `Width` and `Height`.

A more elaborate solution would be to ask yourself a question: which *layout* is needed for my items? There are some standard containers which do the layout themselves and can grow/shrink with the content. For example, if your objects are just aligned in a line, you can go for `StackPanel`.